# how to do classification on the result of stanford-core nlp

Tags: stanford-nlp, sentiment-analysis, text-classification

I have a couple of questions about core nlp and doing classification,

firstly I should say that I have read this questions but still, I am confused:

[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22586658/how-to-train-the-stanford-nlp-sentiment-analysis-tool?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[link2](https://nlp.stanford.edu/wiki/Software/Classifier)

[link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32085525/example-for-stanford-nlp-classifier)

[link4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33712795/questions-about-creating-stanford-corenlp-training-models?rq=1)

and some others related to this,

but my confusion:
when I faced with these links, I was happy that I can do something on the result of the corenlp I got to classify them, then gain the accuracy,

my result like other results of corenlp is something like this:

[image]

but now In these links they are talking about doing labling then using stanford-classifier.

so it seems stanford-classifier is something that do classification on the data like other classification methods, and so there is no way to do classification on the result we get of corenl,

may I ask you to critique me, and share your information regarding this

many thanks

Comment: @StanfordNLPHelp may I ask you to help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the right answer is that, YES stanford classifier is a supervised algorithm,

so if anyone want to do classification on the result of corenlp, it needs some coding , like for example I firstly did the corenlp for very negative ones, then I made the document as the text for very negative text,

then I made another document for very positive, and so on,

finally I had for example two document of the result of corenlp for positive and negative,

Then I used those document for the stanford classifier

hope helps somebody which is new to this area